# Reassembling possibly overlapping string fragments, given the substring and the index

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, data-structures

what would be an elegant method of reassembling possibly overlapping string fragments, given the substring and the index, without using any external libraries?

For example, given (0, "abc") (1, "bcd") (3, "def") (9, "fff") (11,"f")
the implementation should return "abcdef."

The implementation should also be able to keep track of the number of characters that have not yet been assembled. In this case - 3, not 4 because (9, "fff") and (11,"f") are overlapping.

I am coding in c++ and using multimap and recursion, but this seems very slow. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Add your current code/approach as well

Comment: I think it's equivalent to finding connected components of a graph, where each fragment is a vertex, and there's an edge between two fragments if they overlap.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in a single step. Simply merge all sub-strings into a single string. Use a special character for unused spaces (e.g. zeroes). The result is from start to the first unused space. Non-assembled characters are all non-zeroes starting from the first unused space.

First, merge all substrings into a single string. It helps calculating the total length upfront. All unused spaces store zeroes after this operation.

```
struct SubString {
  size_t index;
  std::string substr;
};

auto calculateTotalLength(const std::vector<SubString>& strings) {
  const auto it = std::max_element(
    strings.cbegin(), strings.cend(), [](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
      return (a.index + a.substr.size()) < (b.index + b.substr.size());
  });
  return it != strings.cend() ? it->index + it->substr.size() : 0;
}

auto mergeStrings(const std::vector<SubString>& strings) {
  auto result = std::string(calculateTotalLength(strings), 0);
  for (const auto& s : strings) {
    result.replace(s.index, s.substr.size(), s.substr);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Now you can count all non-assembled characters, starting from the first unused space.

```
auto countNonAssembled(std::string_view s) {
  const auto start = s.find(static_cast<char>(0));
  return start != std::string_view::npos
             ? std::count_if(std::next(s.cbegin(), start), s.cend(),
                             [](auto ch) { return ch != 0; })
             : 0;
}
```

Combine both operations.

```
 auto assemble(const std::vector<SubString>& strings) {
   const auto result = mergeStrings(strings);
   return std::pair{result.substr(0, result.find(static_cast<char>(0))),
                    countNonAssembled(result)};
 }

 const auto [assembled, nonAssembled] =
   assemble({{0, "abc"}, {1, "bcd"}, {3, "def"}, {9, "fff"}, {11, "f"}});

assert(assembled == "abcdef");
assert(nonAssembled == 3);
```

Time complexity is linear to the total number of characters of all sub-strings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I cannot assume that the "special character" will not be included in any of the substrings.

Comment: @NathanLee You can easily change the example and use a `vector<optional<char>>` (for example). You just need some conversions, but the overall algorithm is the same